# List to Dict with simple for beginner

Tags: python

I want this string into the dict like down  below

```
str='hello word i love python ?'
```

Like this

```
dict={hello:word,i:love,pyton:? }
```

Comment: try to write some code, start with simple things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply split the string on whitespace, make the resulting list the element of a singleton list, iterate over that, make an iterator out of that, iterate again, iterate within, and use `next()`:

```
>>> __import__('pprint').pprint({i:next(b) for b in (iter(a) for a in ['hello word i love python ?'.split(None)]) for i in b}, width=20)
{'hello': 'word',
 'i': 'love',
 'python': '?'}
```

Note that I've sent the result to `pprint.pprint` for maximum clarity and readability.

Comment: "maximum clarity and readability" lol

Comment: Wouldn't call this simple...

Comment: @Fejs - It depends on [the](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxLEOcTrO_Q) context.

Comment: bro i says for beginner ,,! not for expert